# Quick Python Questions on encoding to write long list of digits to a file

Tags: python, encoding

From a storage standpoint, why is it more efficient to use ASCII encoding over UTF-8 encoding to write a long list of digits (0-9) to a file?

Also does anyone know what is the most efficient way to create an even smaller file to store the information? I was thinking UTF-16 but not so sure anymore after not being able to find any answer online.

Please help!!

Comment: What does this have to do with Python?

Comment: This file, does it need to be a human-readable text file, or just to be understandable by your own program?

Comment: Because I am working through Python to write a long list of digits (0-9) to a file and need to know why ASCII encoding is more efficient than UTF-8 from a storage standpoint. Would be great if you could provide some insights to the questions.. @Martheen - Would it better if it needs to be a human-readable text file. I'm assuming that is one of the reasons of why ASCII is more efficient?

Comment: For digits, and any other ASCII characters, ASCII and UTF-8 encodings are *exactly the same*.  UTF-16 would take twice the space, I have no idea why you're even considering that.  If storage space is important (and human-readability is not), use compression, such as Python's standard ZLIB module.

Comment: @jasonharper Is compression such as Python's standard ZLIB module the most efficient way to create an even smaller file to store the information? Or is that just one of the options and not the most efficient. Also I believe there are some slight differences with using ASCII over UTF-8 encoding for my scenarion, feel free to correct me if wrong..

Comment: I'm not seeing much valuable responses..Can anyone really help? Just some simple 2 questions that I need an answer to.

Comment: Compressing will automatically take advantage that you're only using a limited set of characters, so the encoding will be rather irrelevant to the output size. They have some CPU & RAM overhead though, so you'd need to explain the scale and expected resource budget for your app.

Comment: You can even pack two decimal digits in a single byte (since 00-99 are only 100 possible values, representable with a byte that allows 256 possible values) with very minimal CPU & RAM overhead. That's why you need to explain your full use case

Comment: @Martheen compression will automatically recognize the limited combination of characters and probably get even better than 2 digits per byte, without any effort on your part.  It's really the best solution, better than trying to roll your own.

Comment: ASCII is a proper subset of UTF-8, so any file consisting of only ASCII characters will be absolutely identical in UTF-8 - you won't be able to tell the difference.  That's one of the things that has made UTF-8 so popular.

Comment: @MarkRansom That assumes a normal situation, OP still haven't mention the actual use case

Comment: @Martheen my point was that with a general purpose compressor like zlib the use case is irrelevant, it will optimize whatever you feed it.

Answer (score 2):

It's unclear what you mean by "the most efficient way". Do you want to do it quickly? To make smaller files? To use less memory in the process?

If you're talking file size - UTF-8 uses 1 byte for the 0-9 numbers just like ASCII. So I expect it to be equivalent. You could use zlib as mentioned in the comments or other compression algorithms to make the file even smaller.

UTF-16 uses 2 bytes at least for every character, so definitely worse. If file size is what you're optimizing for.